# Проблема с адаптацией текста в блоке (чистый css)

Tags: css

Пытаюсь адаптировать текст в блоке на голом css.

html -

```
<div id="updates_container">
    <div class="updates_new">
        <p class="updates_text_top">
            Text
        </p>
        <div class="updates_text_center">
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css -

```
.updates_new
{
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 12em;
    height: 12em;
    margin: 2%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.updates_text_center
{   
    overflow: auto;
    height: 50%;
}
```

[image: Сейчас вот так]

Хочу сделать так, что бы текст был в эти 50%, заранее огромное спасибо, я новичок в css, только учусь

Comment: а в действительности есть слово вот такой длины ? самое длинное слово я которое видел это `автомотовелозапчасти` или расшифровка ДНК - дизоксирибонуклеиновая кислота но такое применяется редка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.updates_new
{
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 12em;
    height: 12em;
    margin: 2%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.updates_text_center
{   
    overflow: auto;
    word-break: break-word;
    height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="updates_container">
    <div class="updates_new">
        <p class="updates_text_top">
            Text
        </p>
        <div class="updates_text_center">
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

добавь word-break: break-word; к updates_text_center.

Так как у тебя не слова а одно большое слово, оно не переводится на новую строку по умолчанию

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогли